# Keeping a laptop screen clean

Tags: technology

Is there any filter or privacy filter I could add to my laptop that would keep dust and marks off of it. I often have to keep cleaning my screen, and wondered if there is some way or hack around this?

Comment: You can buy one: just do an internet search for **laptop screen protector**. However, you then have the problem of keeping *that* clean of dust and marks.

Comment: What kind of marks are on your screen? Is it a touch-sensitive screen (where you could use as clean stylus rather than a yukky finger, say)?

Comment: If it's just dust, canned compressed air can remove all of it in a couple of seconds. Won't help against fingerprints etc., though.

Answer (score 2):

There must be screen protectors available on the internet or in computer shops.

However, the vast majority of people just use a soft piece of cotton cloth to remove the dust. It is cheap, simple, ecologic, fast...

You do not even need a "special" piece of cloth. You can use a perfectly fine wearable t-shirt (or anything else), clean the screen, wash the t-shirt.

---

Of course, I assume there is only plain dust on the screen. If the screen gets oils, glues, pieces of food etc., then the discussion changes completely. In this case, even a dedicated additional screen filter will not prevent the grease and stuff go between the screen and the frame (that is, around the screen).

Comment: Wouldn't a microfibre sheet be better than cotton? The synthetic seems to "grab" and "hold" (technical terms) grease and oil smudges.

Comment: I do not have much experience with microfiber. I know for sure that cotton cannot scratch the screen by itself. If I am not wrong, the microfiber tends to fill quickly with dirt / grease, and after that the results are seriously disappointing. Washing the microfiber will not turn it to the like-new state.